# Shortening a String in Angular JS

Tags: angularjs

I have multiple titles that are longer than 40 characters. I would like to shorten it to 40 characters and add ... if there are more characters.

I want to do something like this but in angular js:

```
if ( title.length > 40){
title = title.substring(0, 40) + '...'
}
```

Comment: And? Its not working, or..?

Comment: I am just looking for a way to do something similar in angular js.

Comment: You don't say and I can't figure out exactly why you'd want to do this unless it is to prevent overflow.  Have you checked out the css property `text-overflow: ellipsis`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest create an angular filter, something like this:

```
angular.module("myApp", [])
.filter('ellipsis', function () {
    return function (input, chars) {
        return input.length > chars ? input.substring(0, chars) + '...' : input;
    };
});

function myCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.text = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed interdum urna vitae nisl volutpat mattis.";
}
```

Usage example:

```
<div ng-controller="myCtrl">
    {{ text | ellipsis:40 }}
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rd13/KLDEZ/4/

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for something a little more 'angular-y' you could write a filter that would allow you to use this in templates:

```
{{title | shorten:25}}!
```

Here's a super-basic [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/markm/6u7yp373/1/) with an example. You might want to add some error-catching, testing, etc: